# Fixing Duped Array Items in Table JavaScript Dedupe Table info

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way to show my array without its previous value being duped on my table whilst keeping my header and making it appear in an inverted order. I have checked the array and it stores the correct information. Now I just want it to display the rows of information one at a time if you guys try it on the fiddle I have provided you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only print the last element of `PageDisplay` inside `QueueTableCreation`:

```
function QueueTableCreation () {
  var element = PageDisplay[PageDisplay.length - 1];
  var row = QueueTable.insertRow(1);
  var PageType = row.insertCell(0);
  var Quality = row.insertCell(1);
  var Time = row.insertCell(2);
  PageType.innerHTML = element[0];
  Quality.innerHTML = element[1];
  Time.innerHTML = element[2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much buddy, I have been trying to do this for awhile.